# Word 2016 Add-in: detect document Save

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office365-apps

I'm developing a Word 2016 Add-in (Word API + Office.js) and I'm wondering if it's possible to get notified when the user is about to save the document.

The document is stored as a LOB on application's database, extracted on a temporary path and opened as a normal file in Word. I need to create a custom handler for Save or Save As command, in order to programmatically update the database with a fresh copy of the document.

Do you think that Word API has a way to set custom handlers on Save and other user events? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this event is currently not supported in Office.js. I recommend in the meantime to expose a button to make the user explicitly save the document on the LOB, either in the ribbon or in the add-in itself.

Comment: Thanks Juan, I agree with you that the custom save button is the only available solution, at least for now. Are you planning to work on such events, in the near future?

Comment: yes we have talked about it and most probably we will in the future.

Comment: I also need this type of functionality, and have raised this as well as another use case for consideration [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18400303-emit-event-for-document-that-is-about-to-be-saved)

Comment: in a more detailed analysis, I do not think they'll ever implement it, since in the online version of 365 saving is automatic and not chosen by the user...

Comment: There's a vote for this feature in the Office Developer Platform's UserVoice page: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18400303-emit-event-for-document-that-is-about-to-be-saved

Comment: Any change to this lately, Juan?

Comment: @JuanBalmori I don't wanna be pushy, but have there been any changes to the status quo?

Comment: Hello all, unfortunately there is no relevant update for this case at this point.