# Save callback handler for office.js add-in

Tags: angularjs, office365, office-js

While developing an Office.js Word add-in, we wanted to perform certain processing on the Document when the user explicitly presses "Ctrl +S" or clicks the "Save /Save As ".
Does the Save operation provide a callback handler for the Office.js? How else can we handle such a scenario?
Typically on save operation, I wanted to reduce the font size of certain content control tag text.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same. It seems there is no such call back available.

[Word 2016 Add-in: detect document Save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157017/word-2016-add-in-detect-document-save)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/845bc73d-766c-4e97-b212-8e516f0c2028/office-javascript-detect-document-save?forum=appsforoffice